# Add prefix to the classes generated by cxf

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, prefix

I use CXF to generate Java classes form wsdl. Is it possible to assign a prefix to all generated classes names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`wsdl2java`](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) tool has an `-b` option:

> -b | binding-name | Specifies JAXWS or JAXB binding files or XMLBeans context files. Use multiple -b flags to specify multiple entries.

The binding file you provide needs to have the following contents:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jxb:typeName prefix="Foo"/>
                <jxb:anonymousTypeName prefix="Foo"/>
                <jxb:elementName prefix="Foo"/>
            </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

This adds `Foo` prefix to classes generated for types, anonymous types and elements. Note that the `schemaLocation` attribute must point to the actual schema.